# life expectancy survival package R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I would like to calculate the life-years lost due to a disease in a way that I correct for other variables in the model (corrected group prognosis method). My dataset is a cohort of individuals for which I have follow-up time till death/censored and a variable whether they died, together with covariates as age, sex and prevalence of disease. I searched the web and I got the impression this should be possible with the survival package in R.

I used the following code which returns probabilities:

```
fit1 <- coxph(Surv(fup_death, death) ~  age + sex + prev_disease, data) 

direct <- survexp( ~prev_disease, data=data, ratetable=fit1)
```

I also tried the survfit function, but than my computer crashes:

```
t<-survfit(fit1, newdata = data)
```

How can I derive the life-expectancy in the ones with the disease and without the disease? Or should I do it differently?

Thanks you in advance!

Best, 
Symen

Answer (score 2):

The calculation for years of life lost is the difference in mean survival.  You can get survfit objects for two separate but comparable conditions like this:

```
fit1 <- coxph(Surv(fup_death, death) ~  age + sex + prev_disease, data) 
survfit_WithDisease <- survfit(fit1,
                             newdata=data.frame(age=50,
                                                sex='m',
                                                prev_disease=TRUE))
survfit_NoDisease <- survfit(fit1,
                             newdata=data.frame(age=50,
                                                sex='m',
                                                prev_disease=FALSE))
```

and by setting `print.rmean=TRUE` you can get estimates of mean survival for each condition.

```
print(survfit_WithDisease,print.rmean=TRUE)
print(survfit_NoDisease,print.rmean=TRUE)
```

Note that mean isn't defined for every survival curve.  There are several options for calculating mean survival when the survival curve does not go all the way to zero, which you should read about in `?print.survfit`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked to get the survival times for the ones with the disease and without the disease.